# To grep the exact word

Tags: grep, rhel

Sample file:

```
t2csi1m9@olth101 [bundleversion_sync]$ cat 1
arun:1.0
arun_kumar:1.2
arun-vinoth:1.3
arun_arun:1.4
t2csi1m9@olth101 [bundleversion_sync]$

t2csi1m9@olth101 [bundleversion_sync]$ grep -w 'arun' 1
arun:1.0
arun-vinoth:1.3
t2csi1m9@olth101 [bundleversion_sync]$
```

When I grep `arun` in file `1`, I am getting 2 outputs where I need only the first one. (`arun:1.0`).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you get two matches because both `arun:1.0` and `arun-vinoth:1.3` contains the word `arun` as a separate word, ending before the non-word characters `:` and `-` in the two results (`_` is considered a word character, which is why `arun_kumar:1.2` is *not* returned with your command).

In this case it would be better to use `^arun:` as the pattern to search for, i.e. any line starting with the string `arun:`.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of *word* for `grep -w` is a sequence of alphanumerical or underscore characters (in the locale or limited to ASCII depending on the implementation/version, and with variations in behaviour if what you search for doesn't start or end in word characters).

Some tools like `zsh`, `vim`, `xterm` let you customize the definition of *word*. But not any `grep` implementation that I know. So if you need another definition of *word*, you'll need to implement it by yourself some other way.

For instance, if your *word* definition should be any sequence of characters other than *colon*, you would do:

```
grep -E '(^|:)arun(:|$)'
```

(`arun` following either (`|`) the start of the line (`^`) or a `:` and followed by either a `:` or the end of the line (`$`)).

Or with standard basic regular expressions:

```
grep '^\(.*:\)\{0,1\}arun\(:.*\)\{0,1\}$'
```

(the start of the line (`^`), optionally (`\{0,1\}`) followed by a sequence of characters (`.*`) ending in `:`, followed by `arun`, optionally followed by a sequence of characters beginning with `:` and the end of the line (`$`)).

Or with PCRE (in addition to  the ERE variant above also supported by PCRE)

```
grep -P '(?<![^:])arun(?![^:])'
```

(`arun` provided it's *not preceded* (`(?<!...)` negative look-behind operator) nor followed (`(?!...)` negative look-ahead operator) by a character other than `:` (`[^:]`); that one you can also use with `grep -o` (to output the word only), `grep -b` (to return its offset within the input), `grep --color` (to highlight the word) like with `-w`)

Or if your *word* definition should be the normal *word* (`[[:alnum:]_]`) plus hyphen:

```
grep -E '(^|[^[:alnum:]_-])arun([^[:alnum:]_-]|$)'
```

and so on.